# Making an html Ruby webserver

Tags: html, ruby, webserver

so, I tried making a simple Ruby Webserver. I tried `ruby -run -e httpd -- -p 5000` and the server started. Then I opened my ip-address:5000/index.html. But the only thing I got was an error saying "504 Gateway Timeout". I also tried using different ports but it didn't work either. So, if anyone has an idea of how to make a webserver with Ruby, that would be great

Comment: *"how to make a webserver"* - please be more specific, do you want to write a webserver from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

A well known one line webserver in Ruby is:

```
ruby -rwebrick -e'WEBrick::HTTPServer.new(:Port => 3000, :DocumentRoot => Dir.pwd).start'
```

Since Ruby 1.9.2 there is also this version:

```
ruby -run -ehttpd . -p3000
```

Both versions serve directory listings and files under:

```
http://localhost:3000/
```